# To convert each number to string and concatenate them

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have javascript array of integers:

```
[1,3,2,9,5,44]
```

I need to convert each number to string and concatenate  them:

```
"1,3,2,9,5,44"
```

How can I implement it ?

Comment: very normal level question without much research.

Comment: `arr.join(',')` simple.

Comment: Make use of jsfiddle and do some research before posting the question. https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the join method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```
yourArray.join(",")
```

Comment: Linking to docs is good, but please for the sake of all things good use a better source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 5):

Use the join method of arrays:

```
[1,3,2,9,5,44].join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var array = [1,3,2,9,5,44];
    var result = array.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript Array `join()` method like this:

```
var arrayOfIntegers = [1,3,2,9,5,44];
var concatenated = arrayOfIntegers.join();
```

Note that the default separator for this method is comma, so the result would be

> 1,3,2,9,5,44

If you want to have the result string some other way, you could pass the separator as an argument to this method, e.g.

```
var arrayOfIntegers = [1,3,2,9,5,44];
var concatenated = arrayOfIntegers.join(" , ");
```

would produce this string

> 1 , 3 , 2 , 9 , 5 , 44

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: Did you miss the tags?

Comment: This is C# way, not javascript

Comment: Yeah, I wrote C# here :)